# WordPress: Display a fallback thumbnail if post doesn't have a featured image

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, loops

I'm working on local WordPress, theme: Twenty Twenty.

I'm trying to get it so that if the article does not have a feature image, then it uses one sourced elsewhere, but no matter what I try it doesn't work. It either displays no image at all, or [this](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1b_QwMwC09BDF9oKZy5nTafYInCSXQG5Jn9iyTdIFpcU/edit?usp=sharing).

Obviously, I don't want the sourced image on the ones that do have a featured image uploaded.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 <?php
/**
 * Displays the featured image
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twenty
 * @since Twenty Twenty 1.0
 */
// if has feature image
if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) {

    $featured_media_inner_classes = '';

    // Make the featured media thinner on archive pages.
    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
        $featured_media_inner_classes .= ' medium';
    }
    ?>

    <figure class="featured-media">

        <div class="featured-media-inner section-inner<?php echo $featured_media_inner_classes; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped -- static output ?>">

            <?php
            the_post_thumbnail();

            $caption = get_the_post_thumbnail_caption();

            if ( $caption ) {
                ?>

                <figcaption class="wp-caption-text"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $caption ); ?></figcaption>

                <?php
            } 
    
            ?>

        <!-- .featured-media -->

             

    

    <?php
} 
// no feature image
else { 
            echo    '<img src="https://st4.depositphotos.com/17828278/24401/v/600/depositphotos_244011872-stock-illustration-image-vector-symbol-missing-available.jpg" alt=""/>';  
        
                
            }
```

**edited WITH image**

```
</header><!-- .archive-header -->

    <div class="grid" id="container grid">
```

```
<div class="entry-header-inner section-inner medium">

        
    <div class="portfolio-header box-row">
        
    
    <h1 class="entry-title heading-size-1"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/portfolio/such-is-my-fortune/">Such Is My Fortune</a></h2></div>
    <div class="feature-img box-row">


<figure class="featured-media">

    <div class="featured-media-inner section-inner medium">

        <img width="800" height="440" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Deaths-Hourglass-800x440.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" data-attachment-id="11" data-permalink="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/deaths-hourglass/" data-orig-file="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Deaths-Hourglass.jpg" data-orig-size="944,1303" data-comments-opened="1" data-image-meta="{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}" data-image-title="Death&#8217;s Hourglass" data-image-description="" data-medium-file="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Deaths-Hourglass-217x300.jpg" data-large-file="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Deaths-Hourglass-742x1024.jpg" /></div><!-- .featured-media-inner -->

</figure>



    </div>      
<div class="post-meta box-row">
    

    
    <div class="post-meta-wrapper post-meta-single post-meta-single-top">

        <ul class="post-meta">

                                <li class="post-author meta-wrapper">
                    <span class="meta-icon">
                        <span class="screen-reader-text">Post author</span>
                        <svg class="svg-icon" aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="20" viewBox="0 0 18 20"><path fill="" d="M18,19 C18,19.5522847 17.5522847,20 17,20 C16.4477153,20 16,19.5522847 16,19 L16,17 C16,15.3431458 14.6568542,14 13,14 L5,14 C3.34314575,14 2,15.3431458 2,17 L2,19 C2,19.5522847 1.55228475,20 1,20 C0.44771525,20 0,19.5522847 0,19 L0,17 C0,14.2385763 2.23857625,12 5,12 L13,12 C15.7614237,12 18,14.2385763 18,17 L18,19 Z M9,10 C6.23857625,10 4,7.76142375 4,5 C4,2.23857625 6.23857625,0 9,0 C11.7614237,0 14,2.23857625 14,5 C14,7.76142375 11.7614237,10 9,10 Z M9,8 C10.6568542,8 12,6.65685425 12,5 C12,3.34314575 10.6568542,2 9,2 C7.34314575,2 6,3.34314575 6,5 C6,6.65685425 7.34314575,8 9,8 Z" /></svg>                      </span>
                    <span class="meta-text">
                        By <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/author/seabear211/">seabear211</a>                      </span>
                </li>
                                    <li class="post-date meta-wrapper">
                    <span class="meta-icon">
                        <span class="screen-reader-text">Post date</span>
                        <svg class="svg-icon" aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="19" viewBox="0 0 18 19"><path fill="" d="M4.60069444,4.09375 L3.25,4.09375 C2.47334957,4.09375 1.84375,4.72334957 1.84375,5.5 L1.84375,7.26736111 L16.15625,7.26736111 L16.15625,5.5 C16.15625,4.72334957 15.5266504,4.09375 14.75,4.09375 L13.3993056,4.09375 L13.3993056,4.55555556 C13.3993056,5.02154581 13.0215458,5.39930556 12.5555556,5.39930556 C12.0895653,5.39930556 11.7118056,5.02154581 11.7118056,4.55555556 L11.7118056,4.09375 L6.28819444,4.09375 L6.28819444,4.55555556 C6.28819444,5.02154581 5.9104347,5.39930556 5.44444444,5.39930556 C4.97845419,5.39930556 4.60069444,5.02154581 4.60069444,4.55555556 L4.60069444,4.09375 Z M6.28819444,2.40625 L11.7118056,2.40625 L11.7118056,1 C11.7118056,0.534009742 12.0895653,0.15625 12.5555556,0.15625 C13.0215458,0.15625 13.3993056,0.534009742 13.3993056,1 L13.3993056,2.40625 L14.75,2.40625 C16.4586309,2.40625 17.84375,3.79136906 17.84375,5.5 L17.84375,15.875 C17.84375,17.5836309 16.4586309,18.96875 14.75,18.96875 L3.25,18.96875 C1.54136906,18.96875 0.15625,17.5836309 0.15625,15.875 L0.15625,5.5 C0.15625,3.79136906 1.54136906,2.40625 3.25,2.40625 L4.60069444,2.40625 L4.60069444,1 C4.60069444,0.534009742 4.97845419,0.15625 5.44444444,0.15625 C5.9104347,0.15625 6.28819444,0.534009742 6.28819444,1 L6.28819444,2.40625 Z M1.84375,8.95486111 L1.84375,15.875 C1.84375,16.6516504 2.47334957,17.28125 3.25,17.28125 L14.75,17.28125 C15.5266504,17.28125 16.15625,16.6516504 16.15625,15.875 L16.15625,8.95486111 L1.84375,8.95486111 Z" /></svg>                      </span>
                    <span class="meta-text">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/portfolio/such-is-my-fortune/">October 19, 2020</a>
                    </span>
                </li>
                                    <li class="post-comment-link meta-wrapper">
                    <span class="meta-icon">
                        <svg class="svg-icon" aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19"><path d="M9.43016863,13.2235931 C9.58624731,13.094699 9.7823475,13.0241935 9.98476849,13.0241935 L15.0564516,13.0241935 C15.8581553,13.0241935 16.5080645,12.3742843 16.5080645,11.5725806 L16.5080645,3.44354839 C16.5080645,2.64184472 15.8581553,1.99193548 15.0564516,1.99193548 L3.44354839,1.99193548 C2.64184472,1.99193548 1.99193548,2.64184472 1.99193548,3.44354839 L1.99193548,11.5725806 C1.99193548,12.3742843 2.64184472,13.0241935 3.44354839,13.0241935 L5.76612903,13.0241935 C6.24715123,13.0241935 6.63709677,13.4141391 6.63709677,13.8951613 L6.63709677,15.5301903 L9.43016863,13.2235931 Z M3.44354839,14.766129 C1.67980032,14.766129 0.25,13.3363287 0.25,11.5725806 L0.25,3.44354839 C0.25,1.67980032 1.67980032,0.25 3.44354839,0.25 L15.0564516,0.25 C16.8201997,0.25 18.25,1.67980032 18.25,3.44354839 L18.25,11.5725806 C18.25,13.3363287 16.8201997,14.766129 15.0564516,14.766129 L10.2979143,14.766129 L6.32072889,18.0506004 C5.75274472,18.5196577 4.89516129,18.1156602 4.89516129,17.3790323 L4.89516129,14.766129 L3.44354839,14.766129 Z" /></svg>                      </span>
                    <span class="meta-text">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/portfolio/such-is-my-fortune/#respond">No Comments<span class="screen-reader-text"> on Such Is My Fortune</span></a>                       </span>
                </li>
                
        </ul><!-- .post-meta -->

    </div><!-- .post-meta-wrapper -->

        
<div class="post-inner thin ">

    <div class="entry-content">
    <div class="portfolio-filter box-row"> 
         <span class='type'><p> Type: <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/project-type/poetry/" rel="tag">Poetry</a> </p></span>
        <span class='genre'><p> </p></span> 
    
</div>
```

**without image**

```
<div class ="box archive-container">
<div class="grid2">

 


<div class="entry-header-inner section-inner medium">

        
    <div class="portfolio-header box-row">
        
    
    <h1 class="entry-title heading-size-1"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/portfolio/vance/">Vance</a></h2></div>
    <div class="feature-img box-row">


<figure class="featured-media">

    <div class="featured-media-inner section-inner medium">

        </div><!-- .featured-media-inner -->

</figure>



    </div>      
<div class="post-meta box-row">
    

    
    <div class="post-meta-wrapper post-meta-single post-meta-single-top">

        <ul class="post-meta">

                                <li class="post-author meta-wrapper">
                    <span class="meta-icon">
                        <span class="screen-reader-text">Post author</span>
                        <svg class="svg-icon" aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="20" viewBox="0 0 18 20"><path fill="" d="M18,19 C18,19.5522847 17.5522847,20 17,20 C16.4477153,20 16,19.5522847 16,19 L16,17 C16,15.3431458 14.6568542,14 13,14 L5,14 C3.34314575,14 2,15.3431458 2,17 L2,19 C2,19.5522847 1.55228475,20 1,20 C0.44771525,20 0,19.5522847 0,19 L0,17 C0,14.2385763 2.23857625,12 5,12 L13,12 C15.7614237,12 18,14.2385763 18,17 L18,19 Z M9,10 C6.23857625,10 4,7.76142375 4,5 C4,2.23857625 6.23857625,0 9,0 C11.7614237,0 14,2.23857625 14,5 C14,7.76142375 11.7614237,10 9,10 Z M9,8 C10.6568542,8 12,6.65685425 12,5 C12,3.34314575 10.6568542,2 9,2 C7.34314575,2 6,3.34314575 6,5 C6,6.65685425 7.34314575,8 9,8 Z" /></svg>                      </span>
                    <span class="meta-text">
                        By <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/author/seabear211/">seabear211</a>                      </span>
                </li>
                                    <li class="post-date meta-wrapper">
                    <span class="meta-icon">
                        <span class="screen-reader-text">Post date</span>
                        <svg class="svg-icon" aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="19" viewBox="0 0 18 19"><path fill="" d="M4.60069444,4.09375 L3.25,4.09375 C2.47334957,4.09375 1.84375,4.72334957 1.84375,5.5 L1.84375,7.26736111 L16.15625,7.26736111 L16.15625,5.5 C16.15625,4.72334957 15.5266504,4.09375 14.75,4.09375 L13.3993056,4.09375 L13.3993056,4.55555556 C13.3993056,5.02154581 13.0215458,5.39930556 12.5555556,5.39930556 C12.0895653,5.39930556 11.7118056,5.02154581 11.7118056,4.55555556 L11.7118056,4.09375 L6.28819444,4.09375 L6.28819444,4.55555556 C6.28819444,5.02154581 5.9104347,5.39930556 5.44444444,5.39930556 C4.97845419,5.39930556 4.60069444,5.02154581 4.60069444,4.55555556 L4.60069444,4.09375 Z M6.28819444,2.40625 L11.7118056,2.40625 L11.7118056,1 C11.7118056,0.534009742 12.0895653,0.15625 12.5555556,0.15625 C13.0215458,0.15625 13.3993056,0.534009742 13.3993056,1 L13.3993056,2.40625 L14.75,2.40625 C16.4586309,2.40625 17.84375,3.79136906 17.84375,5.5 L17.84375,15.875 C17.84375,17.5836309 16.4586309,18.96875 14.75,18.96875 L3.25,18.96875 C1.54136906,18.96875 0.15625,17.5836309 0.15625,15.875 L0.15625,5.5 C0.15625,3.79136906 1.54136906,2.40625 3.25,2.40625 L4.60069444,2.40625 L4.60069444,1 C4.60069444,0.534009742 4.97845419,0.15625 5.44444444,0.15625 C5.9104347,0.15625 6.28819444,0.534009742 6.28819444,1 L6.28819444,2.40625 Z M1.84375,8.95486111 L1.84375,15.875 C1.84375,16.6516504 2.47334957,17.28125 3.25,17.28125 L14.75,17.28125 C15.5266504,17.28125 16.15625,16.6516504 16.15625,15.875 L16.15625,8.95486111 L1.84375,8.95486111 Z" /></svg>                      </span>
                    <span class="meta-text">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/portfolio/vance/">October 14, 2020</a>
                    </span>
                </li>
                                    <li class="post-comment-link meta-wrapper">
                    <span class="meta-icon">
                        <svg class="svg-icon" aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19"><path d="M9.43016863,13.2235931 C9.58624731,13.094699 9.7823475,13.0241935 9.98476849,13.0241935 L15.0564516,13.0241935 C15.8581553,13.0241935 16.5080645,12.3742843 16.5080645,11.5725806 L16.5080645,3.44354839 C16.5080645,2.64184472 15.8581553,1.99193548 15.0564516,1.99193548 L3.44354839,1.99193548 C2.64184472,1.99193548 1.99193548,2.64184472 1.99193548,3.44354839 L1.99193548,11.5725806 C1.99193548,12.3742843 2.64184472,13.0241935 3.44354839,13.0241935 L5.76612903,13.0241935 C6.24715123,13.0241935 6.63709677,13.4141391 6.63709677,13.8951613 L6.63709677,15.5301903 L9.43016863,13.2235931 Z M3.44354839,14.766129 C1.67980032,14.766129 0.25,13.3363287 0.25,11.5725806 L0.25,3.44354839 C0.25,1.67980032 1.67980032,0.25 3.44354839,0.25 L15.0564516,0.25 C16.8201997,0.25 18.25,1.67980032 18.25,3.44354839 L18.25,11.5725806 C18.25,13.3363287 16.8201997,14.766129 15.0564516,14.766129 L10.2979143,14.766129 L6.32072889,18.0506004 C5.75274472,18.5196577 4.89516129,18.1156602 4.89516129,17.3790323 L4.89516129,14.766129 L3.44354839,14.766129 Z" /></svg>                      </span>
                    <span class="meta-text">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/portfolio/vance/#respond">No Comments<span class="screen-reader-text"> on Vance</span></a>                     </span>
                </li>
                
        </ul><!-- .post-meta -->

    </div><!-- .post-meta-wrapper -->

        
<div class="post-inner thin ">

    <div class="entry-content">
    <div class="portfolio-filter box-row"> 
         <span class='type'><p> Type: <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/project-type/novel/" rel="tag">Novel</a> </p></span>
        <span class='genre'><p>Genres: <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/project-tag/adult-themes/" rel="tag">Adult Themes</a> ❦ <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/project-tag/dark-fantasy/" rel="tag">Dark Fantasy</a>  </p></span> 
    
</div>
```

Comment: Your link leads to a protected Google Docs file. That makes it a bit difficult for anyone to see what's going on (not everyone will be willing to share their personal info just to access a document they'll see only once.) It might be a better idea to upload the screenshot(s) somewhere public.

Comment: thank you @cabrerahector I just fixed the link. Do you need the archive file that is calling this file?

Comment: Might not be necessary, and thanks for fixing the Google Doc link so it can be viewed by anyone. So this code you shared is in a separate file that's included in the loop for each post? Also, is `...image-vector-symbol-missing-available.jpg` the image you want to show if the featured image isn't available?

Comment: The way the twenty twenty theme structure seems to work is that it has archive.php which calls on template part: content.php, that also calls the template part: featured-image.php

so far I tried an else{
echo '<img src="https://st4.depositphotos.com/17828278/24401/v/600/depositphotos_244011872-stock-illustration-image-vector-symbol-missing-available.jpg" alt=""/>'; }

placed after the parent if had finished in a nested if

Comment: After the edit you just made, your code should display the fallback image if a post doesn't have a featured image assigned to it or if the post is password protected (however said fallback image will be displayed with a different HTML structure). Is that not the case at the moment?

Comment: no, it displays as the shared slide :/

Comment: Can you please update the question and include the resulting HTML code? I'd like to have a look at the code produced by that PHP code. (Share only the HTML of the image grid, not the entire page :P)

Comment: I think I've done that :)

Comment: That's odd. The `.featured-media` figure tag should not appear on your HTML according to your PHP code. Let's try something different: replace momentarily all of your PHP code with `<?php if ( ! post_password_required() ) { if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo 'display post thumbnail'; } else { echo 'display fallback image'; } } else { echo 'this post is password protected'; }` and check the results.

Comment: I've added the result to to the slide :)

Comment: @cabrerahector as far as I can make out, it feels that there is an image there, even when there is not.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had to get some stuff done at work. Just had a look at the GDoc and reading the code from slide #5 gave me cancer haha. I think your issue is logic related but without seeing the whole code (it seems to me you have omitted part of it here) it's hard to say what's going on. For example, you may want to check the documentation of the `has_post_thumbnail()` and `the_post_thumbnail()` to understand what they do and why reading that slide gave me cancer :P

Comment: nope not admitted, it's a child theme so I'm guessing it's something the theme creators did, thank you.